# fill selected for option incorrect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to click button then set select with option `501`. However, it only works on the first click. The second click then it goes to the first option. Does any one know about this issue?

```js
function test() {
  jQuery('.state_autocomplete option').removeAttr('selected');
  jQuery('.state_autocomplete').attr('value', 'Pernambuco');
  
  jQuery('.state_autocomplete option').each(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).val() == 501) {
      jQuery(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="billing:region_id" name="billing[region_id]" title="Estado" class="form-control validate-select state_autocomplete required-entry" style="" defaultvalue="" value="Pernambuco">
    <option value="">Selecione...</option>
    <option value="496">Minas Gerais</option>
    <option value="499">Paraná</option>
    <option value="498">Paraíba</option>
    <option value="497">Pará</option>
    <option value="500" >Pernambuco</option>
    <option value="501">Piauí</option>
</select>
<button onclick="test()" value='b'>aaa</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is a lot more complicated than it needs to be. Simply use the setter of `val()` to change the selected option. You should also remove the inline `onclick` handler on the button. Use an unobtrusive event handler instead. Something like this:

```js
$('#set').click(function() {
  $('.state_autocomplete').val('501');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="billing:region_id" name="billing[region_id]" title="Estado" class="form-control validate-select state_autocomplete required-entry" style="" defaultvalue="" value="Pernambuco">
  <option value="">Selecione...</option>
  <option value="496">Minas Gerais</option>
  <option value="499">Paraná</option>
  <option value="498">Paraíba</option>
  <option value="497">Pará</option>
  <option value="500" >Pernambuco</option>
  <option value="501">Piauí</option>
</select>
<button id="set" value='b'>aaa</button>
```